# How to add a jpa repository in bean for spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am creating an API using `Spring MVC` and I am facing few issues in integrating `controller`,`service` and `Repository` together. I have integrated Controller with service but facing few issues in integrating service with repository.

Here's the code along with the bean config file:

Controller:

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/clients")
public class ClientController {



    private ClientService clientService;
    @Autowired
    public void setClientService(ClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class ClientService {


    private ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setClientRepository(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }
}
```

Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientModel, String> {

}
```

Bean config file:

```
        <bean id="clientController" class="com.practo.hms.api.clients.ClientController">
        <property name="clientService" value="clientService"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="clientService" class="com.practo.hms.api.clients.ClientService">
        </bean>
```

Even if I add the repository in the bean config,I get a interface error and the api error persists.

Error:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'clientService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through  
 field 'clientRepository'; nested exception is  
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type  
 'com.practo.hms.api.clients.ClientRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which  
 qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations:  
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spring Data Documentation:

> 1.2.3 Creating repository instances
>
> In this section you create instances and bean definitions for the
> repository interfaces defined. One way to do so is using the Spring
> namespace that is shipped with each Spring Data module that supports
> the repository mechanism although we generally recommend to use the
> Java-Config style configuration. XML configuration
>
> Each Spring Data module includes a repositories element that allows
> you to simply define a base package that Spring scans for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

</beans:beans>
```

> In the preceding example, Spring is instructed to scan
> com.acme.repositories and all its subpackages for interfaces extending
> Repository or one of its subinterfaces. For each interface found, the
> infrastructure registers the persistence technology-specific
> FactoryBean to create the appropriate proxies that handle invocations
> of the query methods. Each bean is registered under a bean name that
> is derived from the interface name, so an interface of UserRepository
> would be registered under userRepository. The base-package attribute
> allows wildcards, so that you can define a pattern of scanned
> packages.

Therefore please add `<repositories base-package="package that has ClientRepository" />`

And make sure that your namespaces in the xml have spring-jpa.xsd, and jpa

============ Edited ===============

To add multiple packages:
Example:

```
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.commands.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.infrastructure.*.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.accounting.*.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.useradministration.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.organisation.*.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.portfolio.*" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.mix.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.scheduledjobs.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.template.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.infrastructure.campaigns.sms.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.adhocquery.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.notification.domain"/>
<repositories base-package="org.apache.fineract.infrastructure.campaigns.email.domain"/>
<repositories base-package="org.cs.commands.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.cs.infrastructure.*.domain" />
<repositories base-package="org.cs.portfolio.*" />
<repositories base-package="org.cs.message.*" />
```

Comment: What if I have multiple repositories in different packages?

Comment: @HimanshuRanjan  Create subpackages under a specific package that Spring Data will scan.   
com.hello.repositories.   
com.hello.repositories.subpackageA

Comment: yea,but can I put multiple repositories base?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,got some clarity on how beans and JPA work.

Answer (score 0):

Each Spring Data module includes a repository element that allows you to simply define a base package that Spring scans for you. You can add a repository package inside the <beans:beans />

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.practo.hms.api.clients.repositories" />

</beans:beans>
```

You can learn more from spring.io.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html